# Separating variable names from output strings with no whitespace

Tags: shell-script

I have the following snippet of code where I intend to:

Iterate 5 times the loop;
get a line from a file (each iteration I need the next line fetched);
use the line as a title for a file;
put a timestamp in the beginning of it;
use the line as argument for ping;
print some sentences informing the user about the progress of the code;

The iteration already works.
If I skip the sed part, everything works, but I run the ping 5 times against the same target.
Each line of the file hosts.txt has a single IP address which I intend to ping.

```
for ((i>=1;i<=5;i++))  
do  
sed -n "$i p" hosts.txt | read output  
    touch "$output.txt"  
    date >> "$output.txt"  
    printf "\nComeçando o teste de $output."  
    printf "\nTeste em andamento."  
    ping -c 10 -i 1 "$output" >> "$output.txt"  
done
```

I believe the problem is that I'm doing something wrong about sed syntax. If I try on bash directly `sed -n 1p hosts`, I get the first line. But as I need that number to be $i, if I put $i right before p bash interprets ip as a variable instead of variable i plus argument p after it.

How can I correct this behaviour and not mess this thing again?

Comment: That seems a little bit advanced for me, as I didn't understood half you said. You lost me ath the awk part. :P I'm still a newbie, one day I will get there (knowing awk and how to avoid stupid inefficiences). If you may have any tips for me, I would appreciate, as I'm still learning! :D

Comment: @don_crissti  The fact `sed | read` is inefficient is anecdotal compared to the fact it doesn't work in the first place the way it is used here.

Comment: the loop initialization wasn't doing what you wanted it to do: `i>=1` is a test, not an assignment

Comment: The variable i was initialized outside of the loop. I posted only the loop.

Comment: A simpler version: `i=5; for h in $(head -n "$i" hosts.txt) ; do echo "Testing $h" ; date > "$h.txt" ; ping -c 10 -i 1 "$h" >> "$h.txt" ; done`.   Like your version, this does no checking of the input lines, assumes `hosts.txt` is formatted as exactly one hostname/ip per line...so can break on any lines where that isn't true.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using bash so this should work better:

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))  
do  
    sed -n "$i p" hosts.txt | (
        read output  
        touch "$output.txt"  
        date >> "$output.txt"  
        printf "\nComeçando o teste de $output."  
        printf "\nTeste em andamento."  
        ping -c 10 -i 1 "$output" >> "$output.txt"  
    )
done
```

The issue you were suffering is `bash`, like most shell interpreters outside `ksh` put all pipeline components in a subshell so the `output` variable is immediately lost after being set.

Note also that I corrected your `for` loop which as written had an undefined behavior because the `i` variable was not initialized.

Comment: May I say you're a savior among the earth? :) Why the heck the lack of () was screwing with my code, sire?

Comment: Answer updated with the explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation sire! I saw the correction on the for loop, but I had already initialized the variable i before the loop. Which would be the best practice? Initialize it before the loop or directly on it?

Comment: Doing it inside the loop is the usual and best practice. *however, if the loop variable is already initialized for some reason and you want to use its value, you can leave the first expression empty: `for ((;i<=5;i++)`

Comment: Thank you sire, helped me a bit more than I expected. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, as you have observes, both `i` and `ip` are valid variable names.  So if you want to use the value `$i` immediately followed by the character `p`, you can use bendy braces to clearly delimit where the variable name starts and ends:

```
sed -n "${i}p" hosts.txt | read output
```

Comment: Hey there! I've tried that and simply got a no-go. Got an error messagem from bash when I tried to run my code. Putting ( ) as suggested on another comment solved the problem.

Comment: Unable to replicate your no-go situation.  Tested with `ip=3; sed -n "${i}p" /path/to/file` printing only line three of the file.

Comment: Tried again and got an error message: "ping: unknown host 
intermitencia.sh: line 16: ${$i} p: substituição incorreta". But following the tip on the comment about putting ( ) solved the problem I was having.

Comment: Sed `p` instruction doesn't need to immediately follow the line number so the curly quotes aren't necessary here, a space is sufficient to avoid any class.

Comment: True, but the actual question asked was about separating `$i` from `p`, which is what the bendy braces solve.

Comment: Indeed, but the OP was on a wrong track.

Comment: Which brings up an interesting (and possibly Meta) question:  When there is an A-B issue, is it better to _answer the actual question that was asked_ on U&L, or to _mutate the original question to the actual question, and then answer **that**_?

Comment: @dopeghoti - answer both if possible.  "here's the answer to your question, but this is what you should do instead and why".  If the original question is unanswerable or you think it's so wrong that it shouldn't be answered, explain why.

Comment: @RafaelUmbelino: Did you type `${$i}` (as indicated by the error message you quote)?  Take another look at DopeGhoti's suggestion — you may have typed an extra `$`.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler solution is

```
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))
do
    read output
    date >> "$output.txt"
    printf "\nComeçando o teste de %s." "$output"
    printf "\nTeste em andamento."
    ping -c 10 -i 1 "$output" >> "$output.txt"
done < hosts.txt
```

Note the `< hosts.txt` at the end of the last line, after the `done`. 
This opens `hosts.txt` once and just reads the first five lines from it. 
As mentioned by don_crissti, doing `sed … hosts.txt | read output`
in the loop means that you are reading 
the `hosts.txt` file five times. 
Since the `read output` is parallel with the rest of the loop
(not in a pipeline), the rest of the code in the loop
will have access to the value of `output` read from the file. 
Also (as don also pointed out), you don’t need `touch`;
`command >> file`
will create *`file`* if it doesn’t already exist.

Note that if one of your `hostname.txt` files
already exists, this code will append the new information to it. 
If you want to discard old data and start from scratch,
do `date > "$output.txt"` instead of `date >> "$output.txt"`.

Be careful of passing unknown data directly to `printf`. 
In the (unlikely?) event that one of your “hostnames” has a `%` in it,
your code will garble that name. 
It’s better to pass foreign data to `%s` (to print a string).

You don’t say whether you want to read only the first five lines
of the `hosts.txt` file and then stop,
or whether you want to read the entire file,
and you happen to know that it is five lines long. 
If you want to read the entire file, just do

```
while read output
do
    date >> "$output.txt"
    printf "\nComeçando o teste de %s." "$output"
    printf "\nTeste em andamento."
    ping -c 10 -i 1 "$output" >> "$output.txt"
done < hosts.txt
```

When you get to the end of the file,
the `read output` statement will fail, and the loop will terminate.